Memory overflow error on virtual computer win11Prof
Moved XP Prof and Dos6.22 dual boot onto virtual machine in Windows 11 Professional.
Getting memory overflow error when processing input file.
Any suggestions re memory parameters for virtual computer????
Virtually pure PCTeX user, very little LATeX.
Yes, we have quite a few versions of PCTex in the almost 4 decades of using PCTex BUT the,Herr Professor wants to use his DOS version.
And I am trying to future proof him in virtual environment. Thanks

do you really need a vm, can't you run the pctex executable directly on the windows cmd ?

That does not sound like the kind of thing that other users could understand or answer. That is, it does not seem to have anything to do with TeX, but with virtual Windos operating systems. Best bet: Ask the prof.

PCTeX Is ancient: am I understanding correctly that you are trying to use this rather than TeX Live or MiKTeX? As others observe, if so this is really not a TeX question (certainly not a current TeX question).

Contrary to the other commenters I do think that this question is answerable and on-topic, we have had many similar questions on how to run old versions of distributions on modern systems. That said, the obvious solution is that the professor should start using a modern TeX compiler, this is most probably much less of a change than they think.

The obvious solution is not going more modern because the raison d'etre is speed, accuracy and asci editing power modern systems cannot provide. I have not used the latest edition of PCTEX but I have to concede to Dr RPM that I cannot match his speed nor editing power on newer versions. Where is pCTEX processing and what memory allocations are needed?
